# Importing local python module from directory with __init__.py

Tags: python, package, relative-import

I have been working on a project that requires editing and using an opensource project, lets call it osproj. I renamed the folder containing the edited scripts to osprojmine.

Here is an example directory structure:

```
root/  
    mycode.py  
    osprojmine/  
        __init__.py  
        foo.py  
        bar.py
```

In mycode.py I have the import statement

```
import osprojmine as osproj
```

I have been able to use `osproj.module()` and `osproj.class()` within mycode.py with no issues and everything runs smoothly on my end.

The issue arises when I send the files over to my colleague.
He is getting a
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osprojmine'`

I am using python 3.8.5. He was on 3.9.6 and has tried downgrading.

It seems his python interpreter just isn't recognizing osprojmine as a python package but on my end it does? Very confused. I am relatively new to this field so any and all advice welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colleague (and you for that matter) should run the code as:

```
$ cd root
$ python -m mycode
```

This way the absolute import will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module, python perform lookup in directories specified in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) to find either a `module.py` or `module/__init__.py` file.

By default, after startup `sys.path` contains:

- Current directory (`""`)
- Directories specified by [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)
- Python builtin paths
- Local site-package specified by [`PYTHONUSERBASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUSERBASE)
- System site-package (or virtualenv site-package)

You cannot import `osprojmine` because the `root` directory does not meet any of these conditions.

In a first time you can:

- Run python from `root` directory
- Add `root` directory to your `PYTHONPATH`, permanently or temporary:

  ```sh
  env PYTHONPATH=/path/to/root:${PYTHONPATH} python ...
  ```

But that's poor man's solution, best is to package your project with [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) and install it (evently in [development mode](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html)) either in local site-pakage, named [user scheme](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme), or in virtualenv site-package.